# Finding Process Time taken by a mule flow

Tags: java, mule, batch-processing, anypoint-studio

I'm currently trying to check the time taken by a mule flow, my Mule ESB version is 3.8.3 if that helps.

I am using `<custom-inteceptor>` for this task and thus created a Java class which extends AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor class, the code is as follows,

```
@Override
public MuleEvent last(MuleEvent event, ProcessingTime time, long startTime, boolean exceptionWasThrown)
        throws MuleException 
{

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
    {
    logger.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
            +" Flow : "+event.getFlowConstruct().getName()
            + " Started @ " +startTime+" Ended @ "+endTime
            +" Processing Time : "+(endTime - startTime)+" ms "
            + "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    }
    return event;
}
```

I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when i try to fetch the flow name i.e. at `event.getFlowConstruct().getName()` which is show as above

Also even if i remove it to just check the time taken by the flow to process , it gives 0 ms as the output , also my batch process doesn't execute after it is printed in the consol

I have tried to place the `<custom-inteceptor>` at start as well as the end of the flow but still gives me 0 ms for some reason

The flow is as follows,

```
<flow name="batch-sample-1Flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/bs" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-interceptor class="com.utility.CustomTimeInteceptor"/>
    <batch:execute name="batch-sample-1Batch" doc:name="batch-sample-1Batch"/>

</flow>
```

Yes I am calling a batch process which dosen't execute when `<custom-inteceptor>` is placed before the batch process is called.

Would appreciate if there are other ways to monitor batch processes.

**EDIT:**

I am extending the `AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor` class is it something related to using it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use class **AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor** and   **Interceptor** interface to create custom interceptor... and do coding like this to create Custom Interceptor

```
private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TimerInterceptor.class);

public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date stdate = new Date();
String start = dateFormat.format(stdate);
System.out.println(start);

MuleEvent resultEvent = processNext(event);

Date enddate = new Date();
String end = dateFormat.format(enddate);

if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {

long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        logger.info("Custom Timer : "+resultEvent.getFlowConstruct().getName() + " Start at "+start+" and end at "+end +" it took " + executionTime + "ms to process event ["       + resultEvent.getId() + "]");
}
return resultEvent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mule already has a build in component `<timer-interceptor>` for this. I can be placed within the flow.

```
<flow name="dzone-mule-appsFlow">
    <!-- inbound and your components -->
    <timer-interceptor doc:name="Timer Interceptor"/> 
    <!-- your components -->
</flow>
```

The processing time will be part of the application log. Find out more at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/using-interceptors#timer-interceptor